# How to inline a function for only release build

Tags: c, function, inline, c-preprocessor

```
// common.h
// This is foo function. It has a body.
__inline void foo() { /* something */ }

// a.cpp
#include "common.h" // for foo function
// Call foo

// b.cpp
#include "common.h" // for foo function
// Call foo
```

I would like to inline the *foo* function only when I build for release. I don't want to inline functions for `Debug` build.

I tried it but linker errors annoyed me.
In this case, `foo` function's body is defined in *common.h* header file.
so if I just do

```
//common.h
#if !defined(_DEBUG)
__inline
#endif
void foo() { /* something */ }
```

It will be met a link error in `DEBUG` build. Because two modules try to include common.h.
I have no idea to solve it.
Is it possible?

Comment: Why use `__inline`? Why not `inline` (the standard conformant one)?

Comment: @Nawaz Was *inline* standard? I didn't know that. I saw many __inline in Windows code.

Comment: @Benjamin : Yes. `inline` *is* standard.

Comment: @Nawaz, Does it work for C compiler, Btw

Comment: Any decent compiler has a compile option for this.  No need to alter code.

Comment: @Hans, I work with WDK. Do you know the compiler option of WDK?(I guess you do) I'm searching and searching, but can't find it yet.

Comment: It is /Ob0 to suppress inlining.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47238hez.aspx

Comment: @Nawaz: Microsoft's compiler doesn't support C99 for C code, hence the `__inline` extension.  Unless things have changed in the past few years, virtually nothing done with the WDK (kernel mode) is done with C++.

Comment: Don;t use inline to inline code. Its a waste of time as a human gets it wrong 99% of the time. Let the compiler do it it knows when and why to do the in lining and it will do it automatically without your help or hinderance.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I believe you are in error. Do you have documentation.

Comment: @LokiAstari: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47238hez.aspx says default is "no inlining whatsoever".  In Visual Studio, my C++ projects always defaulted to "expand only inline", but I haven't found docs on that yet.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbf3tbeh.aspx says the linker inlines at will _if_ `/LTCG` is set (it is by default in release builds)

Comment: @MooingDuck: From the page you linked:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47238hez.aspx.  <quote>`/Ob2 is in effect when /O1, /O2 (Minimize Size, Maximize Speed) or /Ox (Full Optimization) is used`</quote> When `/Ob2` is used <quote>`(expansion occurs at the compiler's discretion, often referred to as auto-inlining)`</quote>

Comment: @LokiAstari: oh, learn something new every day.  In MSVC project settings (release), default optimization is "/O2", and default inline expansion is "default", which I means you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental thing to realize is that the `inline` keyword (or Microsoft's `__inline` extension for C - since MSVC doesn't support C99) is essentially a pass to violate the one definition rule. If you think about it - that's all it really is, since the compiler is under no obligation to actually perform any inlining.

So, when you have an `inline` function you're allowed to have the function defined in more than one module. In fact, you're obligated to have it defined in any module that actually uses the function.

However, if you don't declare the function as `inline`, you have to ensure that you have no more than one definition (exactly one if it actually gets used). For non-member functions (all function in C), there are a few ways around this:

- declare the function as `static` to change it's linkage to internal (note that you can have `static inline` functions to begin with).
- in C++ you can place them in an anonymous namespace (which has an effect similar to declaring the static)
- you can use preprocessor manipulation to handle this. It's kind of ugly, but it works, and I've seen the technique used successfully in the wild.  Whether it's worth the effort is another thing altogether - you'll have to decide that yourself.

Basically, what you need to do is have an implementation of the function in a separate .c file, just like if you were following the tradition of a-single-function-per-module coding standard (actually you can do this just as well putting several inline functions in the .c module - but they should all be inline or not inline as a group to keep things from getting too out of hand).  The implementation of the function needs to arrange to be able to be included in a header - so it needs include guards, just like any other header.  Then you use the preprocessor to conditionally include the implementation as part of the header when you want inline functions (so the implementation will be available to all modules), but don't include it if you're not inlining (so you follow the one definition rule in that case):

The `common.h` header:
    // common.h
    #ifndef COMMON_H
    #define COMMON_H

```
#ifdef RELEASE
#define USE_INLINE
#define INLINE __inline
#else
#define INLINE
#endif

INLINE void foo(void);
#ifdef USE_INLINE
#include "foo.c"
#endif

#endif /* COMMON_H */
```

The implementation of `foo()`:

```
// foo.c
#ifndef FOO_C
#define FOO_C

#include <stdio.h>
#include "common.h"


INLINE void foo()
{
    printf("foo\n");
}

#endif /* FOO_C */
```

And an example program:

```
// main.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include "common.h"

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Now if you compile for release:

```
cl /DRELEASE main.c foo.c
```

`foo()` will be `inline` (or `__inline` as the case may be).

If you compile for non-release:

```
cl  test.c foo.c
```

you have a non-inline `foo()`.

And both the compiler and linker are happy in either case.

All that said, I kind of like the suggestion to maybe redefine `INLINE` to be `static` for debugging purposes.

However, ultimately I'm not sure I see the point to any of this really - modern debuggers are able to step through functions that are `inline`, and the debugger probably won't  inline function calls if you disable optimizations. So you can set breakpoints inside the inline function as well and have it work fine in non-optimized builds.

I'm not sure exactly what you're end-goal in this really is. What's the drawback to leaving the functions as `inline` in debug/non-optimized builds?

Comment: Debugging a crashdump with WinDbg, inlined function doesn't match source line. WinDbg just shows me *inlined_function_name+0x10* even if I have a correct pdb and source file.

Answer (score 8):

The "easy" solution would be this:

```
#if !defined(_DEBUG) || defined(NDEBUG)
#define INLINE inline
#else
#define INLINE static
#endif
```

`static` is necessary to silence linking errors and get around the One Definition Rule.

A **better** solution would be to simply disable inlining project wide for debugging. GCC supports the `-wno-inline-functions` and `-fno-inline-small-functions` options to counteract those optimizations, and it also does *not* enable inlining for `-O1` or lower (and probably `-Os` as well). Most compilers have similar options.

I call the latter a better solution because it should instruct the compiler to ignore the `inline` hint, eliminating the need for pesky preprocessor directives.

Comment: +1 for compiler flags. This is better because the compiler might choose to ignore your inline statements or inline functions not declared as such.

Comment: A better solution would be to just leave the inline flag (to make sure the linker handles it correctly). Ignore all the flag stuff let the compiler decide if it needs to inline. By introducing static you are opining yourself up-to to subtle bugs when part of the library is complied with an one version of the function while another part of the library is built with a new version of the function. The debugger will work just as well if the code is inlined or not.

Comment: @Martin York: I agree, but I have encountered some problems using GNU GDB when there are any optimizations enabled - single-stepping through a program jumps around to seemingly-random lines, and it's hard to follow what's happening. The solution is to shut off all optimizations. Granted, it's probably a defect in GDB.

Answer (score 3):

```
#ifdef RELEASE
#define INLINE __inline
#else
#define INLINE
#endif
```

Then

```
// common.h
INLINE void foo() { /* something */ }

// a.cpp
#include "common.h" // for foo function
// Call foo

// b.cpp
#include "common.h" // for foo function
// Call foo
```

then define `RELEASE` for the release version. of course you can see from this there are lots of ways to do it.

Comment: At least use standard conformant keyword `inline`, instead of windows extension `__inline`.

Comment: @Nawaz I only used __inline because op did. I assumed it was for a reason.

Comment: This will not work for builds that define `INLINE` to nothing - the linker will complain about too many definitions of `foo()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare header only functions as non-inline. You could declare them as static (a.k.a. C-style static), but that will generate a copy of the function (including local static variables, if any) in each translation unit. A better solution is to leave it as inline. In debug mode when optimizations are disabled compilers usually don't inline any functions.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases release flags are not defined. Typically debug flags are defined.
_DEBUG is defined by most compilers, so there is no need to define a release flag:

More practical:

```
#ifndef _DEBUG
    __inline void foo() { /* something */ }
#else 
     //some alternative
#endif
```

Comment: Use an include guard:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H
 

// define foo here
 
#endif

Answer (score 0):

Use compiler conditionals and define a compile time flag.

**Example:**

```
#ifdef RELEASE_BUILD_FLAG
  //Run inline function
#else
  //some alternative
#endif
```